# Does Trump ban on Iranian citizens prevent doing exchange studentship in the US?

Tags: usa, denial-of-entry, iranian-citizens, visa-bans, student-visas

I'm Iranian and currently doing a PhD degree in Canada. I might need to do an exchange studentship in the US sometime soon. I had heard that Iranians citizens are exempt from the ban, but I'm wondering if that includes exchange students too (say, for a year of doing research). I'd appreciate if you provide references with your answers as well.

PS: my filed of study is in humanities, if that's relevant.

Comment: For Iranian passport holders, the travel ban bans all immigrant and nonimmigrant visas except F, M, and J visas. Exchange students would be on J visas, so would not be banned.